# How can i down load data when the iphone have some animation running?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

in ios animation have the  highest priority,if some animation running like a tableview scrolling the other work should be paused to ensure the animation smoothly.In my app when the UITableCell appear i start a NSURLConnection to download an Image,but if i don't stop scrolling the tableview the image can't be downloaded.i want to download the image while the tableView is scrolling.I have to know the download progress to set a progressview in the UITableViewCell.
Thank you.

Comment: i got it ,ASIHttpRequest is Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that that really happens that scrolling blocks downloading but if u got stutters in your UI you can use threads.

You can use `PerformSelectorInBackground` to download the image on a different thread and use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to update its progress info to be displayed on the screen. that should ensure nothing blocks the other.
its important that you don't access objects created on one thread through a different thread. so progress info should be created and used on the main thread.